# Trane Furnace Fan Works, But Heater Won't Run

Tags: hvac, furnace, heater

As stated, my heat isn't coming on.

When this started:
Everything has been all fine and dandy all winter. The other day I ran the fan only for a few hours without the heat.
After this, my heat would no longer turn on.

I figured maybe my pilot light had gone out, so I went and checked. Turns out I have an electric pilot light.

I've done some troubleshooting already.

- 10A round fuse on the side of the heater is good. Replaced it with new just to check that off.
- Breaker was not flipped. Cut power and reengaged power just to check that off.
- Thermostat can engage the furnace fan by setting it to "Fan On".
  Setting the heat causes it to call for heat (*click* noise). Heat does not come on.
- Gas dial on inside of furnace is set to "on". I turned it to off and cut power, then reengaged everything before trying to call for heat from the thermostat just to check it off.

What am I missing here? Could something have failed while I was running the fan?

I have a Trane model BLU068L942A1. Probably from the 80's.

Comment: Is the electronic ignition the type that sparks? If so does it go click and lights the pilot and then stops clicking? Or is it continuously clicking?

Comment: It is never clicking. When the thermostat is set to heat, nothing happens on the heater side.

Comment: Try to jumper the R and W at the furnace.

Comment: I'm think it's the ignition module but we gotta rule out some things.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I'll get on that tomorrow.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that when you switched the fan switch to the on position and back off that you didn't accidentally move the system switch from heat to cool.